# How do insert channel entry via SQL?

Tags: channel, entry, entryid

I'm trying to port a table to a channel. Can anyone tell me the basics of what's involved? So far what I think is:

1) Insert record into exp_channel_titles
2) Get entry_id that was just generated for 1)
3) Insert record into exp_channel_data with entry_id from 2)

Is that it? I'm not sure if any more relationships exist. Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, that is it for a basic channel entry. If your channel has categories or relationship fields, or any advanced third-party fieldtypes (such as Matrix or Playa), there will be more inserts required.

Comment: i have upto field_id_200.For insert in some of the fields i first need to check exp_channel_fields and then will have to write query accordingly..would this be appropriate.I personally feel importer moudule does a very good job..but i am trying to automate by setting up a cron and my query will be hard coded.A mysql query will be fired ..what i am uncertain about is ..is there a better way?